# Smooth image rotation in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, mxml

I am trying to rotate a PNG image around its centre point so that I can use it as a wait icon.

This seems to be the way to go but there is a noticeable delay before the animation repeats.

```
<s:Parallel id="animateTimer" target="{timerImg}" repeatCount="0" repeatDelay="0" duration="1500">
    <s:Rotate angleFrom="0" angleTo="360" autoCenterTransform="true"/>
</s:Parallel>
```

Can anybody shed some light on this for me? Why when I have set the repeat delay to 0 does it have a noticeable delay before it repeats?

Comment: How quickly does it rotate (I'm wondering if the delay might be noticeable because 0=360)? And why are you using a [`Parallel`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/effects/Parallel.html) for one effect?

Comment: Isn't it due to the default value of `easer` being `spark.effects.easing.Sine(.5).`

Comment: I agree with @jswolf19 try changing the `angleTo` to be 359 instead of 360, because it might be that it rotates to 360, then starts at 0 which would cause a tiny bit of delay

Comment: @jswolf19 I am using parallel because there will be other efects added once I have solved this.  Also setting the angle to 359 has no effect.

Comment: @Dai, have you tried changing the easer as Kodiak suggested?

Comment: @jswolf19, I don't understand how to use or change it, all of the options seem to speed up or slow down the animation which I do not want.

Comment: Nevermind @jswolf19, I set it to linear to see what would happen and it is smooth now, from the documentation I expected a different result.

Comment: @Dai, a [linear easer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/effects/easing/Linear.html) should do what you want.

Comment: @Dai, Glad that worked for you. Now post the answer ^_^

Comment: @jswolf19, Well I was hoping either you or @Kodiak would post it so I could give you some rep but OK.

Comment: @Dai, you did the legwork to find the solution, we just pointed you in the right direction ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution turned out to look like this:

(took away the parallel in this example for simplicity)

```
<s:Rotate angleFrom="0" angleTo="360" autoCenterTransform="true" id="animateTimer" target="{timerImg}" 
              repeatCount="0" duration="1500" easer="{new spark.effects.easing.Linear()}"/>
```